# Does isomorphism of $\operatorname{Hom}$ imply isomorphism of modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity $1\neq 0$. Suppose $M,N$ are $R$-modules. If $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,-)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(N,-)$, is it true that $M\cong N$? What if we repalce $\operatorname{Hom}_R$ by $\operatorname{Ext}^i_R$ for $i>0$?

Comment: From $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(N,N)$, the identity $\text{id}_N$ corresponds with a map $\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$; and from $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(N,M)$, the identity $\text{id}_M$ corresponds with a map $\psi \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(N,M)$. Prove that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are inverses to each other.

Comment: Using $\text{Ext}^i_R$, for $i>0$, is not enough. For example, if $M$ is a projective module, it will be $\text{Ext}^i_R(M,-)=0$, for all $i>0$, but there are non-isomorphic projective modules (take $R$ and $R\oplus R$).

Comment: @azif00 Could you explain why $ \varphi$ and $\psi$ are inverse to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a consequence of [Yoneda Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) in $Mod_R$.

Yoneda embedding in $Mod_R$ is a functor $Y : Mod_R^{op} \longrightarrow [Mod_R,Mod_R]$ such that $Y(M):=Hom_R(M,-)$ for any $R$-module $M$, and for any $R$-module homomorphism $f: N\rightarrow M$, $Y(f) : Hom_R(M,-) \Longrightarrow Hom_R(N,-)$ is a natural transformation acting via pre-composition with $f$.

As a corollary of Yoneda lemma we get our thesis :

> Yoneda embedding is a fully faithful functor.
> In particular $Y$ reflects isomorphisms, meaning that if $Y(f) : Hom_R(M,-) \Longrightarrow Hom_R(N,-)$ is an isomorphsm, then $f:N\rightarrow M$ is an isomorphism.

If you are not confident with Yoneda, you can explicitely construct the isomorphism $M\cong N$ as follows.

Let $\alpha : Hom_R(M,-)\Longrightarrow Hom_R(N,-)$ be the natural isomorphism of $R$-modules. Then $\alpha_N : Hom_R(M,N)\rightarrow Hom_R(N,N)$ and $\alpha_M : Hom_R(M,M)\rightarrow Hom_R(N,M)$ are isomorphims.
Consider $f:=(\alpha_N)^{-1}(1_N)$, and $g :=\alpha_M(1_M)$ and the commutative diagram arising from naturality of $\alpha$:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Hom_R(M,N) @> \alpha_N >> Hom_R(N,N)\\
@V {g \ \circ -} VV @VV {g \ \circ -} V \\
Hom_R(M,M) @> \alpha_M >> Hom_R(N,M)\\
\end{CD}
$$

Now we have $\alpha_M(g \circ f)=\alpha_M \circ(g\circ -)(f)=(g\circ -)\circ\alpha_N(f)=(g\circ -)(1_N)=g\circ 1_N=g$, thus $g \circ f=(\alpha_M)^{-1}(g)=1_M$, since $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.
Similarly, one can show that $f\circ g=1_N$.
Then $f:M\rightarrow N$ is an $R$-module isomorphism, and $M\cong N$.